# What happened to my reputations?

Tags: support, reputation

Why does it happen sometimes that reputations go down without any notifications ? Other day When I logged out the reputation was $912$. Next day when I logged in again the reputation became $908$. There were no vote downs nor any message or notifications. What happened can please anyone tell ?

Comment: Does your [reputation tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/166713/abstraction?tab=reputation) mention any reputation changes from yesterday?

Comment: @ArthurFischer No

Comment: There is a checkbox at the bottom: "show removed posts". See what happens if it's  checked. As for "no notification", yes this is how it works.

Comment: Is something shown for yesterday in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation)? (AFAIK your reputation breakdown in this form is only visible to you, but the link is the same for any user.) At the end you can see *reputation from suggested edits*. (But I do not know how to find out the same number for yesterday.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if questions to which you made suggested edits have been removed.  The 2 points per suggested edit that had been added were then removed from your reputation.

Comment: Without any notification ??

Comment: @Abstraction: As you know, currently [top-bar notifications are not made for reputation decreases](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16777/8348). That you see nothing in your reputation tab is probably due to not having achieved [10K rep](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), meaning that you cannot see the deleted posts of other users. This is somewhat surprising, as the [MSE reputation faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/214632) indicates that you should see a »removed« indicator in your rep tab.